# How create a routing event handler in Symfony

Tags: symfony, routes

I want to know if it's possible to execute code when a request that targets a certain route is made. I recently learned to perform authentication using authenticators which resemble what I want to create but for security: You either specify which routes to be intercepted by the authenticator in security.yml or you can do it manually in the supports() method. In my case, I have route "test_route" that is used to add new resources to the database (POST request) but I also want to generate user notifications. I could just create the notification object in the controller's action or via a service that gets called in the action but I have quite a few of these use cases and I would like to centralize this execution. I want to know if I could have a single file where I can specify which routes that my handler will fire upon.

Comment: your "problem description" sounds like a diary entry, and it's like ... only the last two sentences get somewhat close to a problem someone might have. the answer is probably "yeah, you might do it in one file", but so far, I have no clue, what you're doing. examples (conceptually) of when this should trigger and not trigger and some code your wrote, would probably help a lot.

Comment: @Jakumi don't know how to explain myself more. Also, the reason why I resolved to SO is because I can't find anything useful in the official documentations so a starter code doesn't make sense at all since what I want isn't an example rather to point me to the right resource, hopefully.

Comment: I feel your pain. it usually comes down to describing the bigger picture then close in on the problem as far as possible. since I don't really know anything about your project ... I'll just start with my assumptions, which you can adopt/adapt into your problem description: "my project provides a plattform for people to trade their cars. when a user posts his car, other users who are interested in buying are notified, when certain parameters match." ... because, to be honest, I don't understand the meaning of multiple routes you mention. elaborate.

Comment: In general, especially if your site grows beyond a certain size, you probably don't want to send notifications immediately but add the notification to a queue, which then is processed. (otherwise, the user who is posting, would have to wait, till the request-bound processing of his post is completed ... or not)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Symfony's built-in events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html). You could add an EventListener to either `kernel.request` or `kernel.controller`.

As @Jakumi mentioned in his comment, it might make sense to delay the sending of a notification, i.e. make it asynchronous. Symfony introduced the [messenger component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) just recently which will aid in doing that.

To sum it up:

1. Add an EventListener listening to one of the kernel events.
2. Have it dispatch a message to a queue.
3. Implement a handler that will send this message asynchronously.